Example of a ring-like structure which satisfies this weird distributive property
Let $(R,+,-,*,0,1)$ be a structure that satisfies the standard axioms for commutative rings with unity, except for the distributive property. Instead, we add this axiom: $x * (y + z + w) = (x*y)+(x*z)+(x*w)$. Is there such a structure which satisfies that axiom but not the regular distributive property? Note, in such a structure, $0*x$ will not always be $0$. However, I am having trouble coming up with such a structure, or proving that none exists.

Can someone who voted to close explain this with a comment? (also to help the user improve their question)

I know the answer to this question but probably I should not post it when there are so many close votes?
